# Can placeholder variables be used in AWS Cognito Allowed Callback URLs?

Tags: amazon-cognito

I would like to be able to use a placeholder varialble in a URL listed as a Allowed Callback URL in an AWS Cognito User Pool app client

e.g. Using a URL like this to have the slug field be variable

https://some-domain/${slug}/loginOauth

Is there any way to do this?

I have tried using the variable notation used in API Gateway to map Stage Variables but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. AWS Cognito doesn't support placeholders in callback URLs because of security reasons.